# Blender Python Script doesn't show in Add ons List

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am just trying to generate some random geometry to get a low poly environment. Therefore I wanted to use a script that randomizes the vertex position. I dropped the python file into ..scripts/addons/. But when i move to user preferences in blender and search for it, it won't show.

Does any of you know what I am doing wrong? I also tried to install the script via the user preferences panel itself, but the same happend, nothing!

```
#!BPY

"""Registration info for Blender menus Name: 'Vertex Noise' Blender: 2.43    Group: 'Mesh' Tip: 'add some random distortion to a selected mesh' """ 

__author__ = "Sammler Rene" __url__ = ("http://www.blender.org", "http://www.sammler-mediengestaltung.com") __version__ = "v080305"

__bpydoc__ = """\ ***** BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK *****

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc, 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA.

***** END GPL LICENCE BLOCK ***** --------------------------------------------------------------------------

This script allows to distort the selected vertex points along the specified directions. """

import Blender from Blender.Draw import * from Blender.BGL import * from Blender.Object import * from Blender.Mesh import * from Blender.Window import * from Blender.Types import * from Blender.Mathutils import * from random import *


def ExportConfig():     conf = {}

conf["X"] = tgl_x.val   conf["Y"] = tgl_y.val   conf["Z"] = tgl_z.val   conf["LOC"] = tgl_local.val     conf["GLOB"] = tgl_global.val   conf["NORM"] = tgl_normal.val   conf["ZERO_1"] = set_zero_1.val         conf["ZERO_2"] = set_zero_2.val 

conf["MIN"] = min.val   conf["MAX"] = max.val   conf["R_SEED"] = r_seed.val

Blender.Registry.SetKey("VERTEXNOISE", conf, True)

def ImportConfig():     global tgl_x, tgl_y, tgl_z, min, max, r_seed,set_zero_1,set_zero_2,tgl_global,tgl_local,tgl_normal

conf = Blender.Registry.GetKey("VERTEXNOISE", True)

if not conf:        return

try:        tgl_x.val=conf["X"]         tgl_y.val=conf["Y"]         tgl_z.val=conf["Z"]         tgl_local.val=conf["LOC"]       tgl_global.val=conf["GLOB"]         tgl_normal.val=conf["NORM"]         set_zero_1.val=conf["ZERO_1"]       set_zero_2.val=conf["ZERO_2"]   

    min.val=conf["MIN"]         max.val=conf["MAX"]         r_seed.val=conf["R_SEED"]   except KeyError:        pass

  def type_check(obj_list):     global failur   ret = 0     if len(obj_list) == 0:      failur = "ERROR: Select a Meshobject!!"         ret = 1     elif type(obj_list[0].getData()) != NMeshType:      failur = "ERROR: Select a Meshobject!!"         ret = 1     else: failur = ""   return ret

def calc_verts_global(vertex, direction, value, trans_mat):     val = 0     if vertex.sel:      val = uniform(value[0], value[1])

    vec = Vector(direction)*val

    vec = vec * trans_mat

    vertex.co[0] = vec[0] + vertex.co[0]        vertex.co[1] = vec[1] + vertex.co[1]        vertex.co[2] = vec[2] + vertex.co[2]

def calc_verts_local(vertex, direction, value):     val = 0     if vertex.sel:      val = uniform(value[0], value[1])

    vec = Vector(direction)*val

    vertex.co[0] = vec[0] + vertex.co[0]        vertex.co[1] = vec[1] + vertex.co[1]        vertex.co[2] = vec[2] + vertex.co[2]        

def calc_verts_normal(vertex, value):   val = 0     if vertex.sel:      val = uniform(value[0], value[1])

    vec = vertex.no*val

    vertex.co[0] = vec[0] + vertex.co[0]        vertex.co[1] = vec[1] + vertex.co[1]        vertex.co[2] = vec[2] + vertex.co[2]


def Event(evt, val):    if evt == QKEY:         ExportConfig()      Exit()      return

def BEvent(evt):    global tgl_x, tgl_y, tgl_z, min, max, r_seed,set_zero_1,set_zero_2,tgl_global,tgl_local,tgl_normal

if evt == 11:       if type_check(Blender.Object.GetSelected()) == 0:           edit_mode = EditMode()          if EditMode(): EditMode(0)          obj_lst = Blender.Object.GetSelected()          if len(obj_lst) > 0:                mesh = obj_lst[0].getData(False,True)               if r_seed.val > 0: seed(r_seed.val)

            intervall = [min.val,max.val]               if set_zero_1.val: intervall[0] = 0.0               if set_zero_2.val: intervall[1] = 0.0

            if tgl_global.val:                  zero_matrix = Matrix([1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1])                   obj_matrix = Matrix(obj_lst[0].getMatrix())                     obj_matrix[3] = [0,0,0,1]                   transform_matrix = obj_matrix.invert() * zero_matrix                    [calc_verts_global(vertex, [tgl_x.val,tgl_y.val,tgl_z.val],intervall,transform_matrix) for vertex in mesh.verts]                elif tgl_local.val:                     [calc_verts_local(vertex, [tgl_x.val,tgl_y.val,tgl_z.val],intervall) for vertex in mesh.verts]                              else:                   [calc_verts_normal(vertex,intervall) for vertex in mesh.verts]              


        if edit_mode: EditMode(1)           elif evt == 10:         ExportConfig()      Exit()      return  elif evt == 12:         min.val = min.val * -1  elif evt == 13:         max.val = max.val * -1          elif evt == 14:         min.val = max.val   elif evt == 15:         max.val = min.val       elif evt == 6:      if tgl_global.val == 0:             tgl_global.val = 1      else:           tgl_local.val = 0           tgl_normal.val = 0  elif evt == 7:      if tgl_local.val == 0:          tgl_local.val = 1       else:           tgl_global.val = 0          tgl_normal.val = 0  elif evt == 8:      if tgl_normal.val == 0:             tgl_normal.val = 1      else:           tgl_global.val = 0          tgl_local.val = 0           tgl_x.val = 0               tgl_y.val = 0           tgl_z.val = 0   elif evt == 1:      if tgl_normal.val == 1:             tgl_x.val = 0   elif evt == 2:      if tgl_normal.val == 1:             tgl_y.val = 0   elif evt == 3:      if tgl_normal.val == 1:             tgl_z.val = 0       

Blender.Redraw()

def GUI():  global tgl_x, tgl_y, tgl_z, min, max, r_seed,set_zero_1,set_zero_2, tgl_global, tgl_local, tgl_normal, failur

glColor3f(0.7, 0.7, 0.7)    glRecti(15, 50, 205, 255)       glColor3f(0.9, 0.9, 0.9)    glRecti(15, 30, 205, 50)    glColor3f(0.65, 0.65, 0.65)     glRecti(15, 255, 205, 275)  glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0)  glRasterPos2f(20,262)           Text("Vertex Noise")        

tgl_global = Toggle("Global", 6, 20, 230, 60, 20, tgl_global.val, "distort to global coordinates")  tgl_local = Toggle("Local", 7, 80, 230, 60, 20, tgl_local.val, "distort to local coordinates")  tgl_normal = Toggle("Normal", 8, 140, 230, 60, 20, tgl_normal.val, "distort to the vertex normals")

min = Number("Min: ", 0, 20, 205, 100, 20, min.val, -100.0, 100.0, "the minimal distortion")

neg_1 = Button("neg", 12, 20, 180, 60, 20, "negate the min value")  cop_1 = Button("= max", 14, 80, 180, 60, 20, "copy the max value to min")   set_zero_1 = Toggle("use 0", 4, 140, 180, 60, 20, set_zero_1.val, "use 0 insted the inserted min value")

max = Number("Max: ", 0, 20, 155,100, 20, max.val, -100.0, 100.0, "the maximal distortion")

neg_2 = Button("neg", 13, 20, 130, 60, 20, "negate the max value")  cop_2 = Button("= min", 15, 80, 130, 60, 20, "copy the min value to max")   set_zero_2 = Toggle("use 0", 5, 140, 130, 60, 20, set_zero_2.val, "use 0 insted the inserted max value")

r_seed = Number("Seed: ", 0, 20, 105,110, 20, r_seed.val, -100.0, 100.0, "")

tgl_x = Toggle("X", 1, 20, 80, 60, 20, tgl_x.val, "distort to x direction")     tgl_y = Toggle("Y", 2, 80, 80, 60, 20, tgl_y.val, "distort to y direction")     tgl_z = Toggle("Z", 3, 140, 80, 60, 20, tgl_z.val, "distort to z direction")

quit = Button("Quit", 10, 20, 55, 80, 20, "")   ok = Button("OK", 11, 120, 55, 80, 20, "")

glColor3f(0.15, 0.15, 0.15)

glRasterPos2f(150,210)  Text(str(min.val)[0:6])

glRasterPos2f(150,160)  Text(str(max.val)[0:6])

glRasterPos2f(150,110)  Text(str(r_seed.val)[0:6])  

glRasterPos2f(105,20)       Text("created by Rene Sammler", "tiny")     glRasterPos2f(75,12)        Text("(sammler-mediengestaltung.com)", "tiny")  glRasterPos2f(150,4)        Text("(v 08 03 05)", "tiny")    glColor3f(1, 0.0, 0.0)  glRasterPos2f(20,35)        Text(failur)    

tgl_x = Create(0) tgl_y = Create(0) tgl_z = Create(0) tgl_local = Create(1) tgl_global = Create(0) tgl_normal = Create(0) set_zero_1 = Create(0) set_zero_2 = Create(0) failur = ""

min = Create(0.0000) max = Create(0.0000) r_seed = Create(0.0000)

ImportConfig() Register(GUI, Event, BEvent)
```

Cheers
-Marten

Comment: So, we should guess that there's a typpo on line 32? Post the code, that's probably the source

Comment: @someonewithpc here you gooo!

Comment: Your code is for Blender 2.49, the Blender module has been replaced with bpy. More than likely your question will not receive support.

Comment: See, @Slim Marten, there's your problem, next time post the code along with the post.

Comment: Find an updated tutorial, and follow it

Comment: @someonewithpc oh I feel kinda dump now. Thanks, in the meanwhile i already found a newer script that works fine for me. Thanks for bearing my stupidity. I am not really into coding especially not python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the script, "Blender: 2.43" is listed as the version. There have been major changes to the blender API in 2.5+. That addon will not run in anything higher then 2.49b unless you convert it.